# Get the value of -webkit-transform of an element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit

I'm manipulating a div with the new cool css3 way of doing a transform like this:

```
$("#thediv").css("-webkit-transform","translate(-770px, 0px)");
```

Later on in the script I thought to get the value of the transform like this:

```
$("#thediv").css("-webkit-transform");
```

It returns a matrix like this: *matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -770, 0)*

What I can't figure out is how to get the 5th value (-770) of this matrix...

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your matrix is a 4x4 transformation matrix:

[image: matrix stuff]

The -770 corresponds to the *v<sub>x</sub>*. To extract it, construct a `WebkitCSSMatrix` object:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle($('#thediv').get(0));  // Need the DOM object
var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);

console.log(matrix.m41);  // -770
```

Comment: Thank you. To save time somebody looking for `translateY`, it's `matrix[5]`.

Comment: WebKitCSSMatrix is not supported by Firefox or Opera

Comment: @koosa: Well, yeah. Neither of them use the WebKit rendering engine. I don't think they have equivalents to WebKitCSSMatrix.

Comment: @Blender - yep so I think yckart's answer might be better to use for the moment

Comment: You shouldn't just give a Chrome/Safari answer without actually stating that. This answer is pretty useless in everyday web development.

Comment: @30secondstosam: The question was tagged `webkit` and my answer clearly uses `WebKitCSSMatrix`, so what's the issue?

Comment: There is an alternative: Just replace `WebKitCSSMatrix` with the alternate `DOMMatrix`. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix

Answer (score 30):

You could split the string into an array and get the desired value as usual. Here's a little helper function that does the split part.

```
function matrixToArray(str) {
  return str.match(/\d+/g);
}
```

**Update**

To preserve decimals: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`

and negatives: `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -770, 0)`

```
function matrixToArray(str) {
  return str.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
}
```

**Update2**

`RegExp` based solution that preserves decimal and negative numbers:

```
function matrixToArray(str) {
  return str.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g);
}

matrixToArray('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'); // => ['0', '0', '0', '0.5']
matrixToArray('matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -770, 0)'); // => ['1', '0', '0', '1', '-770', '0']
```

Comment: This is a much more flexible solution, and the Update 2 example is very useful, because usually iterating over the various matches of a RegExp.exec is a lot more hazardous. +10 if I could.

Comment: I think this answer is much better than the one above for most purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the WebkitCSSMatrix object. http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitCSSMatrixClassReference/WebKitCSSMatrix/WebKitCSSMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009363

This object has as its attributes the matrix elements. It also provides convenience functions for various transformations.

Comment: Looks also nice, but a little bit to complicated right now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry, as of today, that link is broken :(

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the matrix string value, is that jQuery's `css` function is obtaining the *computed style* (the result of `window.getComputedStyle($("#thediv")[0]).webkitTransform`).

To get the actual string value which you set it to in the previous call ("`translate(-770px, 0px)`") you can use:

```
var t = $("#thediv")[0].style.webkitTransform;
```

From that you could just use string methods to get the `x` value, e.g:

```
t.substring(t.indexOf("(") + 1, t.indexOf(",") - 2)
```

which gives `-770`.  However, note that this is only acceptable if you know that the value exists and is in the form you're using (with just a `translate(xpx, ypx)`, since other values are valid!

If you'd prefer to use the computed style, then (to add to @Maz's suggestion), to get the 5th value (the `x` transform), you can do:

```
new WebKitCSSMatrix($("#thediv").css("-webkit-transform")).e;
```

To get the sixth one (the `y` transform) you use the `f` property of the matrix.

Comment: Is this method of getting the original string value going to work across all major browsers?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. generally anything with a "vendor prefix" (e.g. "ms", "webkit", "o", "moz") is platform specific.

Comment: In any case, I found an alternate solution to my original problem, which was animating the transformation: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqAU2/) (not my code)

Answer (score 2):

Since I constantly need to use jQuery together with TweenMax and since TweenMax already took care of all the parsing of various types of transformation strings as well as compatibility issues, I wrote a tiny jquery plugin [here](https://github.com/Luxiyalu/jquery-transformer) (more of a wrap up of gsap's) that could directly access these values like this:

```
$('#ele').transform('rotationX') // returns 0
$('#ele').transform('x')         // returns value of translate-x
```

The list of properties you could get/set, along with their initial properties:

```
perspective: 0
rotation: 0
rotationX: 0
rotationY: 0
scaleX: 1
scaleY: 1
scaleZ: 1
skewX: 0
skewY: 0
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0
zOrigin: 0
```

Paste from my other answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I have coded the simplest solution that ALSO works in Safari, Chrome AND Firefox :)

The trick is NOT to reference the

```
.css("transform")
```

but the

```
.css("translate")
```

property instead :

```
var matrix = $("#thediv").css('translate');
console.log ( matrix[1] ); 
// matrix result is of form [x , y]
// so for example matrix[1] will give you the transformY value :)
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: matrix[1]}, 750);
```

I'm delighted to have found such an economical solution since I have been dealing with 3D transforms in webkit and 2D transforms in Firefox simultaneously, and using this method the property values can be accessed directly :)

Comment: chrome -> 

$(element).css('transform')
 = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -759.640625, 0)"
$(element).css('translate')
 = undefined

Comment: This gives me undefined as well.