# retrieve the same offsetX on touch like mouse event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hello I am trying to get the offsetX,Y of touch event which should be identical to offsetX of mouse event. To do so I have used this code:

```
 ev.offsetX = ev.targetTouches[0].pageX- canvasName.offsetLeft
```

I have even tried to simulate the touch event into mouse event but for that purpose i need the offsetX/Y, which is unavailable in touch event. Is there any way offsetX/Y can be calculated for touch? Please help

Comment: and what is `canvasName`? try to use `canvasName.clientX`

Comment: canvasName is the id of the canvas

Comment: stop! then you need to do something like `canvas = getElementById(canvasName)` and then you can do `canvas.offsetLeft`

Comment: sorry couldn't explain it thoroughly, i have already done the getElementById stuff, i am getting the correct values for mouse events, i just need the same for touch...i am also looking at your solution

Answer (score 51):

I use this

```
var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - rect.left;
var y = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - rect.top;
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly for transformed (eg rotated) elements. offsetX gives the value in the element's local coordinate system before transformations; this does not.

Comment: @trembyJust do x / scaleRatio and y / scaleRatio.

Comment: The - rect.left was what I needed since e.pageX was returning the wrong value

Comment: @W.leto you'd need the entire matrix transform inverse, not just a scaling. So that's not really a workable solution.

Answer (score 15):

The best answer here don't work for me, on webpage with scrolling! This will work better:

```
var bcr = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = e.targetTouches[0].clientX - bcr.x;
var y = e.targetTouches[0].clientY - bcr.y;
```

I used it to solve my problem.

Comment: How is this any different than the top accepted answer by @alex-nikulin?

Comment: pageX/Y -> clientX/Y

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question but the first in a google of "offsetX touch event".. I ended up using something like this after the research I did.

```
function getOffsetPosition(evt, parent){
    var position = {
        x: (evt.targetTouches) ? evt.targetTouches[0].pageX : evt.clientX,
        y: (evt.targetTouches) ? evt.targetTouches[0].pageY : evt.clientY
    };

    while(parent.offsetParent){
        position.x -= parent.offsetLeft - parent.scrollLeft;
        position.y -= parent.offsetTop - parent.scrollTop;

        parent = parent.offsetParent;
    }

    return position;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to think this works better than the top answer by @alex-nikulin? Because that one is much more compact.

Comment: @alex-nikulin's answer doesn't account for offset, I've updated my answer to include a cleaned up and smaller adaptation of what I was trying to get across. As well as one that shows how you could have other needs for a particular use case

Comment: Also, getBoundingClientRect is computationally heavy. In situations where you'd be calling this a lot, which given the nature of its use would be almost every time, you will notice it

Comment: I was really excited to find an answer that doesn't use getBoundingClientRect(), but (unfortunately) I don't think this would be faster.  This does essentially the same calculations as `getBoundingClientRect()`, but using a js thread instead of native threads.  It's too bad, because getBoundingClientRect() is quite heavy.

Comment: I only use getBoundingClientRect() on touchstart instead of touchmove, you could store the value to reuse in each touchmove as you only need the change in clientX/Y and that will be much less computationally heavy. The issue I'm having though is it doesn't seem to take into account whenever you're zoomed in, I'm on iOS 14 Safari.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [PointerEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent) instead of touch events, they have more properties. For example:

```
div.addEventListener('pointermove', console.log);
```

Output:

```
isTrusted: true
altKey: false
altitudeAngle: 1.5707963267948966
azimuthAngle: 0
bubbles: true
button: -1
buttons: 1
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
clientX: 203
clientY: 483
composed: true
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
fromElement: null
height: 23
isPrimary: true
layerX: 203
layerY: 177
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: -1
offsetX: 203
offsetY: 177.6875
pageX: 203
pageY: 483
pointerId: 9
pointerType: "touch"
pressure: 1
relatedTarget: null
returnValue: true
screenX: 734
screenY: 621
shiftKey: false
sourceCapabilities: null
tangentialPressure: 0
tiltX: 0
tiltY: 0
toElement: null
twist: 0
type: "pointermove"
which: 0
width: 23
x: 203
y: 483
[[Prototype]]: PointerEvent
```

Usage example: [MDN: Pinch zoom gestures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Pinch_zoom_gestures)

Comment: You saved me hours of unsuccessful searching to handle mouse and touch events in a coherent way! +100!

Answer (score 3):

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/1997890

```
function recoverOffsetValues(e) {
    var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX - (rect.left - bodyRect.left);
    var y = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY - (rect.top - bodyRect.top);

    return [x, y];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
const {x, y, width, height} = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
const offsetX = (e.touches[0].clientX-x)/width*e.target.offsetWidth;
const offsetY = (e.touches[0].clientY-y)/height*e.target.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: But _why_? What set of conditions requires this approach compared to the other approaches?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `clientX`/`clientY` properties of mouse event (or `pageX`/`pageY`) if you have scrolling on your page.

As for your solution. It can be corrected by using `getElementById(canvasName).clientX`

```
ev.offsetX = ev.targetTouches[0].pageX - getElementById(canvasName).clientX
```

`canvasName.offsetLeft` is offset of `canvasName` with respect to it's parent. So if you want to use `offsetLeft` you should do something like the following

```
var left = 0,
elem = getElementById(canvasName);

while(elem) {
  left = left + parseInt(elem.offsetLeft);
  elem = elem.offsetParent;         
}

ev.offsetX = ev.targetTouches[0].pageX - left
```

Comment: I need offsetX value of mouse event inside a touch event...clientX is not for touchevent

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery touchend events, the layerX and layerY attributes provide the relative x and y, but do not take into account the transform.  So I manually applied the transform by grabbing the transform scale values from the css.

e = the touchend event from jQuery

parent = the jQuery object of the parent element where the "transform" is applied.  For me it was `$(e.target.parentNode);`

```
const layerX = e.originalEvent.layerX;
const layerY = e.originalEvent.layerY;
const currentScale = 1 / parseFloat(parent.css('transform').match(/-?[\d\.]+/g)[0]);

const offsetX = layerX * currentScale;
const offsetY = layerY * currentScale;
```

To make the last two lines compatible with touch and click events:

```
const offsetX = e.offsetX || layerX * currentScaleX;
const offsetY = e.offsetY || layerY * currentScaleY;
```

Reference for grabbing transform values:  [Fetch the css value of transform directly using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601209/fetch-the-css-value-of-transform-directly-using-jquery)

If you are using Reactjs `onClick` then you can get the layerX and layerY values with: `e.nativeEvent.layerX`.  For some reason the layerX and layerY are not available on the React touch events.  If you do need to use the React `onTouchEnd`:

```
const rect = e.nativeEvent.target.getBoundingClientRect();       
const layerX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - rect.left;
const layerY = e.changedTouches[0].clientY - rect.top;
const currentScale = 1 / parseFloat(parent.css('transform').match(/-?[\d\.]+/g)[0]);
const offsetX = layerX * currentScale;
const offsetY = layerY * currentScale;
```

Note: It is better to store the values of the transform in Redux rather than grabbing them with jQuery.