# Get the applied css property-identifiers

Tags: javascript, css, properties, matrix, transform

How can i get the currently applied `CSS` property-identifiers from an element (excluding the value)?

Or rather: How to get the elements e.g. `translate`, `skew`, `rotate` or `rect`? I don't mean the complete returned string like: `rect(300px 0px 0px 300px)`. I mean just the `property-identifiers`...

I'm not a really familiar with RegExp but maybe can that do the trick?

So for better interpretation purposes:

I need to check for that, change some values (via matrix-array) and reapply them back to the element again.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/5968313/1250044
function matrixToArray(matrix) {
    return matrix.substr(7, matrix.length - 8).split(', ');
}

$("#foo").css("clip","rect(300px 0px 0px 300px)");
var matrix = matrixToArray($("#foo").css("clip"));

                              // If `#foo` has something else
                              // applied than `clip`, then
                    --- ˅ --- // is that not really dynamically
$("#bar").css("clip", "rect(" + matrix[0] + matrix[1] + matrix[2] + matrix[3] + ")");
```

Comment: You can detect with jQuery.

Comment: @Pete Read my question, I need the property without values...

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...

Quite simple:

```
var getIdentifier = function(str) {
    return str.split('(')[0];
};
```

`getIdentifier( 'rect(300px 0px 0px 300px)' ) // => 'rect'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle):

```
// your elemenet
var el;

// get the transformations applied:
var transform = window.getComputedStyle( el ).transform;
```

This will, however, get you a `matrix` in most of the cases and not the individual transformations applied.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.,

```
$(ele).css('rotate')
```

To detect, check if the return length >　0

```
$(ele).css('rotate').length
```

Comment: That does not answer my question really ;)