# Is there a way to target the first and last element in each row using jQuery isotope?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have an masonry isotope grid that has n number of rows with two column sizes: 160px by 160px and 320px by 320px and I'd like to assign different styles to the first and last element of each row. My rows could have anywhere from 4 elements to 7 elements. I've been struggling with this for a bit, and wondering if it's possible.

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 960px;"
class="isotope">
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="two_by_two">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_two">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="two_by_two">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_two">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="two_by_two">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_two">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="one_by_one">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/products/gucci.png"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#grid {
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:55px;
    margin-bottom:200px;
    width:1140px
}
#grid .thumb {
    width:97%;
    height:97%
}
#grid .one_by_one {
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    background:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/assets/cell_1x1.png);
    cursor:pointer
}
#grid .one_by_two {
    width:160px;
    height:320px;
    background:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/assets/cell_1x2.png);
    cursor:pointer
}
#grid .two_by_two {
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
    background:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-images/assets/cell_2x2.png);
    cursor:pointer
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#grid").isotope masonry: layoutMode: 'fitRows'
```

**View my Jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/TDma4/

Comment: Please include some sample HTML to clarify your question

Comment: I added code and a jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I have an answer ready for you, but adding the sample code makes your question a lot clearer :). Will respond if I do come up with an answer

Comment: Any luck with the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way to approach the problem.

**Working Solution:** http://jsbin.com/ufuleb/21/

**CSS**

```
.first, .last {
  border:2px dashed blue;
  opacity:.75;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#grid").isotope(
    { layoutMode : 'fitRows' });

// Last div element
$("#grid div:last-child").addClass("last");

var maxWidth = 0;

// Use max to handle last div
$("#grid div").each(function (i) {  
  matrix = matrixToArray($(this).css("-transform"));

  // identify first elements
  if ( parseInt(matrix[4],10) == 0 ) {
    $(this).addClass("first");
  }

  // identify last elements
  if ( parseInt(matrix[4],10) > parseInt(maxWidth,10) ) { 
    maxWidth = matrix[4];
  } else {      
    $(this).prev().addClass("last");
    maxWidth = 0;
  } 
});

// Util function for parsing -webkit-transform
function matrixToArray(matrix) {    
    return matrix.substr(7, matrix.length-8).split(', ');
}
```

Loop through each `div` and track the current `xT` value ([CSS -webkit-transform](http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/webkit/css_-webkit-transform.cfm)). Whenever the maximum value is passed, just update the previous value which should be the last element of each row. The very last element is handled with `:last-child`. *Note that this solution also handles the overall `#grid` width changing.*

**Example Output**

[image: Example output]

This could probably be optimized further but at least provides a starting point.

I got some help from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968313/1085891

**For reference:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:last-child
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: If you change `-webkit-transform` to `transform`, it should work in other browsers (e.g. Firefox). Also, is the last child (in DOM order) guaranteed to be the last element in the last row?

Comment: Updated my code. Also, I couldn't find a test case where the last child element wasn't the element in the last row with `layoutMode: 'fitRows'`.

Answer (score 7):

Isotope has a [`itemPositionDataEnabled`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#itempositiondataenabled) option that exposes the position of each element. Using this, along with a [`onLayout`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#onlayout) handler, you can compute the first and last elements of each row ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/rERvZ/7/)):

```
$('#grid').isotope({
    itemPositionDataEnabled: true,
    onLayout: function (elems, instance) {
        var items, rows, numRows, row, prev, i;

        // gather info for each element
        items = elems.map(function () {
            var el = $(this), pos = el.data('isotope-item-position');
            return {
                x: pos.x,
                y: pos.y,
                w: el.width(),
                h: el.height(),
                el: el
            };
        });

        // first pass to find the first and last items of each row
        rows = [];
        i = {};
        items.each(function () {
            var y = this.y, r = i[y];
            if (!r) {
                r = {
                    y: y,
                    first: null,
                    last: null
                };
                rows.push(r);
                i[y] = r;
            }
            if (!r.first || this.x < r.first.x) {
                r.first = this;
            }
            if (!r.last || this.x > r.last.x) {
                r.last = this;
            }
        });
        rows.sort(function (a, b) { return a.y - b.y; });
        numRows = rows.length;

        // compare items for each row against the previous row
        for (prev = rows[0], i = 1; i < numRows; prev = row, i++) {
            row = rows[i];
            if (prev.first.x < row.first.x &&
                    prev.first.y + prev.first.h > row.y) {
                row.first = prev.first;
            }
            if (prev.last.x + prev.last.w > row.last.x + row.last.w &&
                    prev.last.y + prev.last.h > row.y) {
                row.last = prev.last;
            }
        }

        // assign classes to first and last elements
        elems.removeClass('first last');
        $.each(rows, function () {
            this.first.el.addClass('first');
            this.last.el.addClass('last');
        });
    }
});
```

**Update:** Fixed algorithm based on JSuar's feedback

**Update #2:** Fixed an issue when items are taller than 2 rows

Comment: @JSuar can you provide an example? The onLayout handler is called every time Isotope lays out the elements

Comment: It's an edge case but if you set `width:520px;` one of the larger elements won't be caught as a last element.

Answer (score 1):

Mike,  If you are feeling adventurous you can extend Isotop to do this.   I pulled the following from http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html

Any additional properties you are looking to do you can do in the .each block

```
_fitRowsLayout : function( $elems ) {
  var instance = this,
      containerWidth = this.element.width(),
      props = this.fitRows;

  $elems.each( function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        atomW = $this.outerWidth(true),
        atomH = $this.outerHeight(true);

    if ( props.x !== 0 && atomW + props.x > containerWidth ) {
      // if this element cannot fit in the current row
      props.x = 0;
      props.y = props.height;
    } 

    // position the atom
    instance._pushPosition( $this, props.x, props.y );

    props.height = Math.max( props.y + atomH, props.height );
    props.x += atomW;

  });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/86WVw/1/

**Edit**:
isotope now uses translate3d, edited to use both translate n translate3d
http://jsfiddle.net/86WVw/3/

additional css:

```
[style*="translate(0px"], [style*="translate3d(0px"], .border { // .border is class for end of row item, you can change it to whatever you want
    border: 3px dotted #f00;
}
```

additioan js:

```
gw = $('#grid').width(); // get grid width
w = $('#grid').width(); // to find smallest width, take a big number first
$('#grid>div').each(function(){ // iterate through tiles
    if ($(this).width()<w) // if width smaller then assumed smallest width
        w = $(this).width(); // change smallest width
});

var x;
for (x = w; x < gw; x += w) // iterate translated tiles from smallest width to grid width
{
    var elms = $('[style*="translate3d('+x+'px"], [style*="translate('+x+'px"]');
    $(elms).each(function(){
        if ((x+$(this).width())>(gw-w)) // if tiles left + tile width reach end of grid
        $(this).addClass('border'); // apply class
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is much simpler than it seems.
The size of the box is a multiple of a common matrix.
This is my approach.

```
var columnsWidth = 100; // the base matrix width
var columns = 8; // the number of columns available (container.width / columnsWidth)

$.each(box, function() {
    var box = $(this) // the current box
    var boxSize = [2,2] // obtained subdividing size by matrix
    var maximumXChord = (columns - boxSize[0]) * columnsWidth // the maximum X available

    if (box.x == maximumXChord) { // check if the current X Chords is equal to the maximum
        console.log('the box is the last of this row!')
    } else if (box.x == 0) { // check if the the X is 0
        console.log('the box is the first of this row!') 
    }
})
```

That's all!