# How to get value translateX by javascript

Tags: javascript

content element initialize with javascript

```
content.children[0].style.transform = "translateX(" + (-200) + "px) scaleX(" + 1.6 + ") scaleY(" + 1.2 + ")";
```

How to get value of translateX for this element ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.hello');

function getTranslateX() {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.transform);
  console.log('translateX: ', matrix.m41);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getTranslateX);

// set inline-style transform to element as given from question
element.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-200) + "px) scaleX(" + 1.6 + ") scaleY(" + 1.2 + ")";
```

```css
.hello {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
<button type="button">get value</button>
```

Same as above example but using deprecated: `style.webkitTransform`

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.hello');

function getTranslateX() {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
  console.log('translateX: ', matrix.m41);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getTranslateX);

// set inline-style transform to element as given from question
element.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-200) + "px) scaleX(" + 1.6 + ") scaleY(" + 1.2 + ")";
```

```css
.hello {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
<button type="button">get value</button>
```

If you wonder why `matrix.m41` that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968313/2008111)

Comment: is there a cross browser solution?

Comment: @chovy in 2019 you should DOMMatrix https://caniuse.com/#feat=dommatrix

Comment: @DOMMatrix currently isn't supported by IE, edge or safari either.

Comment: @Tom check the link just above your comment from Scott (https://caniuse.com/#feat=dommatrix) maybe it works with `WebKitCSSMatrix`

Comment: deprecated, now it's `style.transform`

Comment: For anyone wondering: translateY is m5

Comment: @ChrisM, is translateY not matrix.m42?

Answer (score 32):

If you want to be fancy (and, for that matter, exact), you can use a special method on the `Window` object. Namely, the [`.getComputedStyle()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Let's say your element has an `id` of `myElement`. You could get do as follows:

```
const myEl = document.getElementById('myElement');
window.getComputedStyle(myEl).transform;
```

Of course, what is returned reflects the collective effect of all other transformations applied upon the same element (*e.g.*, rotations, translations, scalings, *etc*.). Furthermore, when querying for the value of `transform` style property, we tend to get something ugly in the form of a matrix transformation (*e.g.*, `"matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.939693, 0.34202, 0, 0, -0.34202, 0.939693, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)"`). We probably want to avoid this avenue since, at best, it leaves us with the hassle of having to parse a string output.

My recommendation, then, would be to stay simple and just query the `transform` property on the [`style` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) (more specifically, a [`CSSStyleDeclaration` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)). Check it:

```
const transformStyle = document.getElementById('myElement').style.transform
// => "translateX(1239.32px)"
```

Again, we get a string-type output, but the hassle has been greatly eased by the simplicity of that string. By leveraging the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method of the `String` object's prototype and passing a simple regular expression, we can trim the value of `transformStyle` to just what we want:

```
const translateX = transformStyle.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
// => "1239.32"
```

And if you want that output as a `Number` data type, simply append the `+` unary operator before the whole statement to coerce into such:

```
const translateX_Val = +translateX;
// => 1239.32
```

---

### Edit

Instead of doing

```
window.getComputedStyle(myEl).transform;
```

the safer and recommended approach is probably to instead use the [`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) method:

```
window
  .getComputedStyle(myEl)
  .getPropertyValue('transform');
```

Comment: Brilliantly written.

Comment: It's a good answer except win using the style.transform property you should use a different method to get the value in case there are multiple transforms, OR if there is a different unit being used such as vw.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. To accommodate the possibility of negative values you might tweak the regex thusly, `/[^-?\d.]/g`

Comment: The second simpler option didn't work for me in Chrome, when I inspected the computed transform style with the browser's dev tools it was given as a matrix, which might be a clue as to why it didn't work. I ended up using @caramba's accepted answer which was simpler than it first looked.

Comment: RegEXP! I forgot about it but your answer really helped me!

Comment: isn't safer just to substring from `translateX(` to `)` then extract numbers or units as needed?

Answer (score 30):

A cross browser solution:

```
function getTranslateXY(element) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
    const matrix = new DOMMatrixReadOnly(style.transform)
    return {
        translateX: matrix.m41,
        translateY: matrix.m42
    }
}
```

### Tests

We get this output (in a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) style):

```
>> getTranslateXY(element1)
{translateX: 0, translateY: 0}
>> getTranslateXY(element2)
{translateX: 0, translateY: -90}
>> getTranslateXY(element3)
{translateX: 30, translateY: 0}
>> getTranslateXY(element4)
{translateX: 10, translateY: 20}
>> getTranslateXY(element5)
{translateX: -400, translateY: 500}
```

For those elements as arguments (passed to the aforementioned `getTranslateXY` function):

```
<div/>                                                         // element1 
<div style="transform: translateY(-90px);"/>                   // element2 
<div style="transform: translateX(30px);"/>                    // element3
<div style="transform: translateX(10px) translateY(20px);"/>   // element4
<div style="transform: translate3d(-400px, 500px, 0px);"/>     // element5
```

Pay attention to the mix (or absence) of `translateX` / `translateY` and also [`translate3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d). We get proper results, no matter what CSS function we use (`translate3d` contains values of `translateX` and `translateY`).

### Explanation

Reagrding the matrix: we have 16 properties named `m11`, `m12`, `m13` ... `m41`, `m42`, `m43`, `m44`, that represent the columns and rows of the matrix. We are interested in the fourth column, and in the first and the second row. `m41` holds the `translateX` property, and `m42` holds the `translateY` property.

We use `window.getComputedStyle(element)` instead of `element.style` to get a uniformed representation of the `transform` value (in the form of a matrix), so we won't need to use `regex`, or parsing strings' headache.

### Compatibility

Supported by all major browsers, except the notorious Internet Explorer, achieved by:

- Using [`style.transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) instead of `style.webkitTransform`.
- Using [`DOMMatrixReadOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrixReadOnly) interface instead of `WebKitCSSMatrix`. (`WebKitCSSMatrix` is an alias to [`DOMMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix), which is a mutable version of `DOMMatrixReadOnly`, that inherits properties from it).

I made this summary thanks to the great answers and comments in this thread, so the credit is all yours.

Answer (score 15):

Using matrix parsing method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397066/4094167) I was able to access transformation properties with following code:

```
var transformation = window.getComputedStyle(myEl).getPropertyValue("transform").match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g);
```

If there is no transformation applied then `transformation` object will be `null`, otherwise it will hold array of transformation properties. For 2D transformation it's going to be like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp):

```
matrix(scaleX(),skewY(),skewX(),scaleY(),translateX(),translateY())
```

Answer (score 10):

A **2021** method :

You can use `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("css property")` .

Here the css property would be ("transform") .

The result if was a 2d matrix which contain 6 values like this :

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20)
```

The 5th value is translateX , and the 6th is translateY .

If then you want to manipulate the value from that matrix either increase or decrease
you may use split() method to convert it to an array , then turn the value you got from that array into a number as following :

```
   let matrex = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("transform");
       //matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20)
       let matrexArr = matrex.split(", ");
      //Array(6) [ "matrix(1", "0", "0", "1", "10", "20)" ]
       let translateXNum = parseInt(matrexArr[4]);
       //10
```

NB : I am a **newbie** programmer , sorry if there is something is not clear enough .

Answer (score 5):

You can play with some **experimental features**: [`Element.computedStyleMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap)

> Current support Chrome & Edge (check: [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_computedstylemap))

#### Short answer

For **single** `transform` [ e.g. `transform: translate(40px, 10px);` ]:

- Get the value from index `[0]`:

  ```
  el.computedStyleMap().get('transform')[0].y.value;
  ```

#### Demo:

```js
let {
  value,
  unit
} = document.getElementById('demo').computedStyleMap().get('transform')[0].y;

console.log(value, unit); // 10 "px"
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  align-self: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#orig {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}

#demo {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(40px, 10px); /* << */
}
```

```html
<div id="orig" class="box"></div>
<div id="demo" class="box"></div>
```

---

#### Long answer

For **multi** `transform` [ e.g. `transform: translate(40px, 10px) scale(0.8, 0.5);` ]

- Search for either `instanceof CSSTranslate` or `CSSScale`, …

#### Demo

1. [`Element.computedStyleMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap) ⇒ [`StylePropertyMapReadOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StylePropertyMapReadOnly) instance …
2. … [`StylePropertyMapReadOnly.get('transform')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StylePropertyMapReadOnly/get) ⇒ [`CSSTransformValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSTransformValue)  instance …

   ```
   el.computedStyleMap().get('transform');`
   ```
3. … `.find()` prop. with instanceof [`CSSTranslate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap) …
4. … extract what you need from coordinate props. E.g. Coordinante X

   ```
    const {x: {value, unit}} = [
        ...el.computedStyleMap?.()
        .get('transform')?.values()
    ].find(x => x instanceof CSSTranslate);

    console.log(value, unit); // ➜ 40 'px'
   ```

```js
const el = document.getElementById('demo');
const styleMap = el.computedStyleMap();      // ➜ StylePropertyMapReadOnly
const transform = styleMap.get('transform'); // ➜ CSSTransformValue
// console.log(transform);
/*
CSSTransformValue {
  0: CSSTranslate {
    x: CSSUnitValue {
         value: 40, 
         unit: 'px'
       },
    y: CSSUnitValue {
         value: 10, 
         unit: 'px'
       },
    z: ...
  }, 
  1: CSSScale {
    x: CSSUnitValue {
         value: 0.8, 
         unit: 'number'
       },
    y: CSSUnitValue {
         value: 0.5, 
         unit: 'number'
       }
  }
}
*/

const mx = transform.toMatrix();             // ➜  DOMMatrix
console.log(mx.toString());                  // ➜ 'matrix(0.8,   0,   0, 0.5,  40,  10)'
// console.log(mx)                           //     ⇒       a    b    c    d    e    f  
                                             //     ⇒     m11  m12  m21  m22  m41  m42 
                                        
console.log(transform.toString());           // ➜ 'translate(40px, 10px) scale(0.8, 0.5)' ━┓
const [translate, scale] = transform;        //                                             =
console.log(                                 // ➜ 'translate(40px, 10px) scale(0.8, 0.5)' ━┛
  ...[translate, scale].map(String)
); 

// ... alternative create new CSSTranslate() from CSS string e.g. 'translate(40px, 10px)': 
let translate2 = new CSSTranslate(
  ...translate.toString()                    // ➜ 'translate(40px, 10px)'
  .split(/[(,)]/)                            // ➜ ['translate', '40px', ' 10px', '']
  .slice(1, -1)                              // ➜ ['40px', ' 10px']
  .map(CSSNumericValue.parse)                // ➜ [CSSUnitValue {value: 40, unit: "px"}, ...]
);

const mx2 = translate2.toMatrix();           // ➜  DOMMatrix
console.log(mx2.toString())                  // ➜ 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 40, 10)'
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
align-self: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#orig {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}

#demo {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(40px, 10px) scale(0.8, 0.5) /* << */
}
```

```html
<div id="orig" class="box"></div>
<div id="demo" class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is a suitable answer, but lacks elegance.

Comment: Just replace all your code with `el.computedStyleMap().get('transform')[0].y.value`

Comment: @avalanche1 As long as there is just a single transform fn, index `[0]` works. if there are multiple transform fn´s you need to `find()` the index: `scale(..) transform(..) `  has `CSSTranslate` at `[1]`. Added a "short version" to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add. I think this is important.

Get the css value of the transform property. It will output the values of the 3D matrix.
And you will need a specific number to get the value.

One of the 16 values of a 4x4 homogeneous matrix. For example, m12 represents the value in the first row and second column.
Find the value in the matrix for the css property "transform: scaleY (0);" changing 0 in css to 44 eg.

```
let box = document.querySelector('.menu-1');
let getStyle = getComputedStyle(box);
let matrix = new DOMMatrixReadOnly(getStyle.transform);
console.clear();
console.info("gmatrix.m11 = ", matrix.m11);
console.info("gmatrix.m12 = ", matrix.m12);
console.info("gmatrix.m13 = ", matrix.m13);
console.info("gmatrix.m14 = ", matrix.m14);
console.info("gmatrix.m21 = ", matrix.m21);
console.info("gmatrix.m22 = ", matrix.m22);
console.info("gmatrix.m23 = ", matrix.m23);
console.info("gmatrix.m24 = ", matrix.m24);
console.info("gmatrix.m31 = ", matrix.m31);
console.info("gmatrix.m32 = ", matrix.m32);
console.info("gmatrix.m33 = ", matrix.m33);
console.info("gmatrix.m34 = ", matrix.m34);
console.info("gmatrix.m41 = ", matrix.m41);
console.info("gmatrix.m42 = ", matrix.m42);
console.info("gmatrix.m43 = ", matrix.m43);
console.info("gmatrix.m44 = ", matrix.m44);
```