# After rotation my div moves location and never returns

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I am rotating an "E" to make an eye test, so when the user clicks the directional button the "E" will rotate. My problem is that the "E" changes location after the initial click. I need it to stay in the same position. Here is a GIF of the occurrence:

[image: EMove]

My styling:

```
div.container4 p {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-size: 2em;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;            
    }
```

Code:

```
<div class="container4" style="height:inherit;">
<p id="E">E</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
rotateE: function () {
    var step = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    switch (step) {
        case 1:
            $('#E').css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + 90 + 'deg)' })                
            break;
        case 2:                
            $('#E').css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)' })
            break;
        case 3:                
            $('#E').css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + 270 + 'deg)' })
            break;      
        case 4:
            $('#E').css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + 360 + 'deg)' })
            break;      
        default:

    }
}
```

Something I did notice in dev tools was that the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` gets cancelled out after the first click:

[image: css]

Thank you for any help to correct this.

Comment: You need to combine the `translate(-50%, -50%)` with the `rotate` other wise it will be overwritten eg. `$('#E').css({ 'transform': 'translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(' + 90 + 'deg)' })`

Comment: @Turnip Thank you I have used this and it works, should have posted an answer :)

Comment: @Turnip Do you by any chance know how I can determine which direction or rotation the "E" is in when the click happens, in Javascript?

Comment: Read this: https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/ and also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267189/how-to-get-value-translatex-by-javascript

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform applied with javascript is overwriting the transform specified in CSS. Either add `translate(-50%, -50%)` to the JS transforms or change the styles to avoid using a transform. If you want to center the element you could always use flexbox instead of absolute positioning and transforms.

```
div.container4 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;          
}
```