# How to get @keyframes current transform-value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

ANSWER for the translateX value (thanks to Albert Portnoy):

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
var xVal = parseFloat(style.transform.split(" ")[4].replace(",", ''));
```

How do I get the current transform value of an element which is animated with @keyframes in javascript?

There doesn't seem to be a change of the css value I used (translateX) when it is animated or it has finished

```
<style>
    @keyframes anim {
        from {
            transform: translateX(0px)
        }

        to {
            transform: translateX(400px)
        }
    }

    div {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: black;
        animation: anim 5s forwards linear;
    }
</style>

<div></div>

<script>
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

    function loop() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(div.style);
            loop()
        }, 100)
    }
    loop()

</script>
```

Comment: Just get the [current translate position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267189/how-to-get-value-translatex-by-javascript)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you can probably make use of animation events like [onanimationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onanimationend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (the not yet standard) feature [CSSMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSMatrix).
Another helpful explanation about [Calculating element vertex data from CSS transforms](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/calculating-element-vertex-data-from-css-transforms/)

Here is a running example, note that i used [requestanimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of a callback loop with `setTimeout` to run the code on each frame.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('root');
let count = 0;

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
    console.log('translateX: ', matrix.m41);
    if(count > 100){
      // just to stop the infinite loop...
      return;
    }
    count++;
    loop();
  })
}
loop()
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(400px)
  }
}

#root {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  animation: anim 5s forwards linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. the requestAnimationFrame will certainly help with what I have to do. Is it even necessary to use the CSSMatrix? Does it have any advantages over style.transform.split(" ")[4].replace(",", ''); ? Thanks!