# How do I scale and translate new canvas while copying from another canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

I have one canvas name mainCanvas.

```
<canvas id="mainCanvas" style="width: 1440px; height: 1080px; transform: scale(2);"></canvas>
```

I want copy of this canvas into subCanvas. This is how I copy it:

```
let subCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let subCtx = subCanvas.getContext('2d');
subCtx.drawImage(mainCanvas,0,0);
```

But the scale is not reflecting in subCanvas. I want subCanvas with zoom image of mainCanvas.
How can I add scale and translation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value translateX by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267189/how-to-get-value-translatex-by-javascript)

Comment: I know the scale that is "2". But I want to add that scale to subCtx. and need zoom image on subCanvas

Comment: Well, the `transform: scale` property scales the DOM, not the canvas content

Comment: I explain it in other words. A canvas is a wrapper of pixels, when you say `transform: scale(2)` you are just telling the browser to zoom the view, without changing the pixels inside

Comment: Yes. true. But I want to download a zoom image. So I need a solution to convert scale value into drawImage property. So I can download image exactly same as looks in DOM