# How to get translateX value of a component with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I need to get the `translateX` value of my component.

I followed the instructions of both first and second answers of this post: [How to get value translateX by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267189/how-to-get-value-translatex-by-javascript/42267468)

I checked other posts as well, but most of them suggest the same solutions.

I also checked the `matrix()` documentation. But I am not able to get it right.

I am trying to use `WebKitCSSMatrix` which gives me the matrix, but the position which I believe to be what I need (m41) is `0`, and none of the others is the actual translateX value.

I am also trying with `getComputedStyle`, which gives me this: `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -1352, 0)`, I could work with the fifth value, but I don't know how to extract it, I tried with `m41`, but I am getting `undefined`. I know I could use a `RegEx` to get the fifth value, but I'd like to know if there is a more straightforward way to do that. Besides it would be better to get the value as I set them, as percentage, like in the css file, `200%`

Besides that I tried the simple `element.style.transform`, but here I get an empty string.

I'd like to know two things:

-> What is wrong with my code?

-> How can I actually get the `translateX` value?

```js
function passTeste(arg) {
  
    const element = document.getElementById("mainImage-teste-js")
    
    const transformValue = window.getComputedStyle(element).transform;
    var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(element.webkitTransform);
    
    console.log(element.style.transform) // Returns empty value

    console.log(matrix); // Returns the matrix 
    console.log(transformValue); // Returns =>  matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -1352, 0)
}
```

```css
.container {
      width: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.product__image--mainImage {
        
        display: flex;

        transition: 2s;

        transform: translate(-200%);
}

.product__image--mainImage img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container > p {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: space-between; 
   font-size: 45px; 
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainImage-teste-js" class="container">
    <div class="product__image--mainImage">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOues59dCMXRYVPt6H8XvWGAuPlwHBprFWEw&usqp=CAU" />
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUEwJ_CKwAt4M1k_UTZSUCVUTy2XWjWLdK3w&usqp=CAU" />
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOues59dCMXRYVPt6H8XvWGAuPlwHBprFWEw&usqp=CAU" />
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUEwJ_CKwAt4M1k_UTZSUCVUTy2XWjWLdK3w&usqp=CAU" />
     </div>
     <p onclick="passTeste()">></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: *I know I could use a RegEx to get the fifth value, but I'd like to know if there is a more straightforward way to do that.* --> not really. The only other way is to read the CSS file to extract the value as defined (not trivial too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good, you simply need to apply the computed value to `WebKitCSSMatrix` in order to read the `m41` and since transform is based on the element dimension you can find the percentage value as well:

```js
function passTeste(arg) {

  const element = document.querySelector("#mainImage-teste-js > div")

  const transformValue = window.getComputedStyle(element).transform;
  const w = window.getComputedStyle(element).width;
  var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(transformValue);

  console.log(w);
  console.log(matrix.m41);
  console.log(matrix.m41/parseInt(w)*100+"%");

}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product__image--mainImage {
  display: flex;
  transition: 2s;
  transform: translate(-200%);
}

.product__image--mainImage img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container>p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainImage-teste-js" class="container">
  <div class="product__image--mainImage">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOues59dCMXRYVPt6H8XvWGAuPlwHBprFWEw&usqp=CAU" />
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUEwJ_CKwAt4M1k_UTZSUCVUTy2XWjWLdK3w&usqp=CAU" />
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOues59dCMXRYVPt6H8XvWGAuPlwHBprFWEw&usqp=CAU" />
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUEwJ_CKwAt4M1k_UTZSUCVUTy2XWjWLdK3w&usqp=CAU" />
  </div>
  <p onclick="passTeste()">></p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Berg_Durden you need to either do a calculation like I did (check the update) or read the CSS file as a text to extract the value (not easy)

Comment: Yes, I saw your edit after my last comment. I already deleted it. Both options work great. Thank you very much.