# Realistic CSS perspective look around

Tags: jquery, css, transform, perspective

I have a 3d-like room in `CSS`, and used `jQuery` to add a *look around* effect on mouse move  with `perspective-origin` and a *zoom in/out* effect with `mousewheel.js` that changes the `perspective` amount.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2hxes701/)

But it's not very realistic. It's not like if we were looking around, it just seems that the room is deformed.

So I tried to correct this with `transform: translateY()` on my lateral walls but it's not what I expected.

Do you have any solutions ? Thanks !

PS: Sorry for my english, I'm french ;)

Comment: It is hard to know what you mean by "realistic". CSS Transforms aren't made for making things look realistic. Do you have any examples of the effect you are going for?

Comment: I think you have to translate your room on the Z-axis: $("section .room").css({ transform: 'translateZ('+ (value) +'px)' in the mousewheel event

Comment: Thanks Marouen, I tried on the whole <section> but the room was getting out the screen, but I'll try with .room at once.
@oatmealsnap : something like a FPS game. I know it's not going to be very realistic, I will abuse of CSS 3D furthermore, I just want a bit of interactivity :)

Comment: @MarouenMhiri It's working good for zoom in/out ! Now I have to find a solution to the behavior when the mouse moves.

Comment: oui mon ami c'est pas facile ton truc! au fait il faut combiner mousewheel avec mousemove. Peut être en essayant d'intègrer mousemove dans mousewheel ? :-/

Comment: Oh, tu écris bien français :) Question en passant : `+=`n`px` et `-=`n`px`   ne fonctionne pas avec `transform` ?
@oatmealsnap I found an example of what I want here http://www.bestjquery.com/?Dt0atS0T

Comment: oui là il y'a une possibilité de récupérer les transformX-Y-Z en utilisant ceci :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968227/get-the-value-of-webkit-transform-of-an-element-with-jquery/5968313#5968313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MADE IT ! With a lot of `3d transform`. See the fiddle if you want to see the difference, and the solution ;)

[**BEFORE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2hxes701/) |
[**AFTER**](https://jsfiddle.net/2hxes701/3/)

NOT WORKING WITH FIREFOX :( Okay with Opera, Chrome... I can't find a hack for Firefox about `3d transforms` because I think it's the problem.

Help :)