# How to get transform value of html element in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get transform value of html-element

```
<div (click)="onClick($event)"></div>

onClick(element: HTMLElement) {
    console.log(element.style.transform); // output: translate(0px, 0px)
}
```

but I want these values as numbers i.e. something like this

```
x = element.style.transform.translate.x; // output x = 0
y = element.style.transform.translate.y; // output y = 0
```

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: please have a look at required output, I updated the question, please review

Comment: your given link doesn't fulfill the requirement. Please suggest me the proper code

Comment: Yeah no. That's not gonna happen. Transform doesn't work like that.

Comment: @mwn it is not a place where people have to do things for you. If element has not css style attribute, but css attribute comes from css stylesheet file, you can use getSomputedStyle. Also it is simple enough.

Comment: @Vayrex this is of the best place where people help others excepts arrogant like you. look the answer, someone try to answer this problem.

Comment: @Vayrex So you found the accounts who can downvote the question.

Comment: @mwn When I was a trainee/junior dev, I was asking a lot of simple questions to my boss.
After a while he told: "Guys it seems that you will be asking soon, do I need to press this button or not ?". I was thinking that he is not right, but after a month I learned a lot of small things by self and studied to do research and learn things fast.
So for developer who want to be a good dev, must be able to work with docs and do research. Also I have done vote down only after you told that I'm arrogant.

Comment: @Vayrex you are right but there are consequences when someone posts the question on stack-overflow. I searched for that problem for some time but could not get the required result then I preferred to ask a question instead of spending more time on simple things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here's how you get the values of `translate x,y` :

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
console.log('translateX: ', matrix.m41);
console.log('translateY: ', matrix.m42);
```

computed style : https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

matrix.* : [Get the value of -webkit-transform of an element with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968227/get-the-value-of-webkit-transform-of-an-element-with-jquery/5968313#5968313)

Comment: This is no standard and only works in Safari, ie10, 11 and edge.

Comment: Please give the standard if this is not standard

Comment: @Darkrum did you test it ? i just did and it's working fine on Chrome  ( 64 ) and Firefox ( 56 )

Comment: @Taki Thanks bro, it worked. Please remove that downvote because my question was valid and logical. Nothing was wrong then why someone gave me downvote. Thanks for your kind response

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could help, the downvote wasn't mine but i removed one

Comment: I knew you were not. Glad to see your response